# Windows 7 shows 0 Free memory for 4 GB installed RAM

Tags: windows-7, memory, task-manager

Laptop: Dell Inspiron 1525 Core-2-Duo
Pre-installed RAM: 2GB
Additional installed RAM: 2GB
OS: Windows 7

I have just installed extra 2 GB of RAM in Windows 7 and now it shows total 4 GB RAM.

[image]

After installing it when I look into Windows Task Manager it shows me `0` as `Free Memory`.

[image]

How it's showing 0 Free Memory?

Please, will anybody explain it to me?

How to understand it? Does it require any BIOS setting to be set?

Thanks and advance.

Comment: I think "cached memory" confuses quite a few people. It is memory that is in use only because windows think you or some program might want the information. It can be released instantly when an in-use program actually needs it. Free memory is wasted memory.

Comment: install the 64Bit Windows 7 to make use of your full 4GB RAM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The important thing is to have available memory. not free.

in this post it explains what is  it for

> Available is the only one that matters. Available shows what is
>   capable of being used by Programs. Without paging other lower priority
>   processes out of memory. It is a combination of both Cache and Free.

So don't worry about free memory because it can be used for system things or just reserved for programms

http://www.sevenforums.com/performance-maintenance/114504-diff-between-available-free-physical-memory.html

this is better.
http://brandonlive.com/2010/02/21/measuring-memory-usage-in-windows-7/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: But as the OP has posted when Free drops to 0, the computer slows down regardless of how much the available has.

Answer (score -1):

Use Rammap or Rammap64 depending of your OS.Then in the menu select Empty Standby List.This will free that cached memory.
I see every day this memory eating problem on Win7.When you go low on free memory, your programs run slower.Just Empty Standby List and you'll get back some speed.
But try to use at least of 4Gb of ram on a W7 machine.
I have  8 or 16 ;) eg. On my 8gb gaming system,  before to launch a game I Empty...